# Python 3 string.join() equivalent?

Tags: python, string, methods, python-3.x

I've been using string.join() method in python 2 but it seems like it has been removed in python 3. What is the equivalent method in python 3?

string.join() method let me combine multiple strings together with a string in between every other string. For example, string.join(("a", "b", "c"), ".") would result "a.b.c".

Comment: `string.join` is deprecated in Python 2. So you would use `'.'.join()` in Python 2 too.

Comment: Alright I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: @rubik that is of course unless you `import string` ;)

Comment: @alavin89 I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are saying. *All* the string functions that became methods are deprecated. Whether you import the module or not.

Comment: @rubrik `string` methods are deprecated in favor of `str` methods. In most cases you want to use your pythonic `'.'.join()` approach, but there are legitimate, pythonic uses for `str.join()` (formerly `string.join()`) too. For example, you sometimes want the *joining str* to be configurable at runtime and want to pass the function (along with the *joining str*) on to other elements of a string-processing or NLP pipeline.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`'.'.join()` or `".".join()`.. So any string *instance* has the method `join()`

Comment: By the way, you should be using the methods in 2.x as well.

Answer (score 38):

`str.join()` works fine in Python 3, you just need to get the order of the arguments correct

```
>>> str.join('.', ('a', 'b', 'c'))
'a.b.c'
```

Comment: ... and that is because generally `obj.method(args)` is technically equivalent to the `objclass.method(obj, args)`. My +1. Anyway, the Tim's is more usual in Python.

Comment: Yea, thanks. I personally use @Tim's approach too, when I can. But sometimes you need the `join` function before you have the delimiter string instantiated (to pass to a middleware constructor, serializer, etc).  And @Dennis was looking for the Python3-equivalent to `string.join`, and this is the only one that I'm aware of.

Comment: Yes. I understand the motivation. This is absolutely correct ;)

Answer (score 15):

There are method `join` for string objects:

`".".join(("a","b","c"))`

Answer (score 4):

Visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

```
s=" "
seq=["ab", "cd", "ef"]
print(s.join(seq))
```

> ab cd ef

```
s="."
print(s.join(seq))
```

> ab.cd.ef