# Python 3: Converting A Tuple To A String

Tags: python, string, variables, python-3.x, tuples

I have the following code:

```
var_one = var_two[var_three-1]
var_one = "string_one" + var_1
```

And I need to do the following to it:

```
var_four = 'string_two', var_one
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicity
```

I have tried things such as `str(var_one)` and using `strip` but these did not work.
What can I do to achieve the result I require?

EDIT - Here are what the variables contain:

var_one: new variable

var_two: tuple

var_three: integer

var_four: new

EDIT2:

The line in the program that makes the error is: `os.system(var_four)`

Comment: Are we to assume `var_one` is a tuple? Can you give us a real example of your code? Does the information in this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886669/tuple-to-string

Comment: Um... what is in these variables?

Comment: Added what the variables are to question.

Comment: @birryree As mentioned in the question, using `str(var_one)` does not work in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine as is.

Try running `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in your program to see if you can find the line triggering the error.

**EDIT:** You'll want to use `''.join(var_four)` to convert `var_four` into a string before adding it to whatever it is you want to use it. Please note that this will actually create a new string and not overwrite `var_four`. See [Python 3 string.join() equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668152/python-3-string-join-equivalent)

Also, you should be using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`. See the [Python 3.x documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess).

Answer (score 4):

```
one_big_string = ''.join(tuple)   
print one_big_string
```

Comment: indent code four spaces to put it in a block, instead of using inline backticks.

Comment: @katrielalex - You can't tell me how to live! ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you've written is fine:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 1, x
>>>
```

The problem is that somewhere *else* in your code, you're using `var_four` as a string where it should be a tuple.

BTW, I think it's neater to put parentheses around tuples like this; otherwise I tend to think they're being used in tuple unpacking.

---

EDIT: There are all sorts of ways to join and format strings -- Python is good at that. In somewhat-decreasing order of generality:

```
"{first_thing} {second_thing}".format(first_thing=var_one, second_thing=var_two)

"{0} {1}".format(var_one, var_two)

var_one + var_two
```

Comment: I need var_four to be a string, that is my problem.

Comment: Updated the question with the line that is causing the error.

Comment: @EdenCrow: It's not a string. You __defined__ it not to be a string. It's a tuple. You can _convert_ it to a string in any number of ways, depending on how you want it converted.

Comment: @EdenCrow it looks like you want `"".join(var_four)` i.e. you want to concatenate the elements -- but then `subprocess.Popen` is the recommended way to call external programs from Python.

Comment: So using the `,` in variable assignment causes it to become a tuple? Then how do I make a string from adding `string_two` and `var_one` together?
EDIT: Ninja'd - will have a look at `"".join(var_four)`

Comment: @katrielalex Please move your responses into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` expects a string which will will execute in the shell, but you're giving it a tuple instead.

Imagine we want to run the command `rm -rf /home/mike`. You might be doing something like

```
binary_and_option = 'rm -rf'
directory = '/home/mike'

command = binary_and_option, directory # This is the tuple 
                                       #    ('rm -rf', '/home/mike') 
                                       # it is NOT the string 
                                       #     'rm -rf /home/mike'

os.system(command) # this clearly won't work, since it's just 
                   # os.system(('rm -rf', '/home/mike'))
```

what you want to do instead is

```
command = "%d %d" % (binary_and_option, directory)
```

to assemble the string. You are probably thinking comma assembles str-ed objects together with spaces in between, but that's only for `print`; it's not how strings work in general.

---

**But *wait*, there's more!** You **never** want to use `os.system`, especially when you're going to build commands. It invokes the shell (which introduces unncessary security risks and other penalties) and has an inflexible API. Instead, use the `subprocess` module.

```
import subprocess 

binary_and_option = ['rm', '-rf']
directory = '/home/mike'

command = binary_and_option + [directory]

subprocess.call(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str(my_tuple)
```

This seems too easy, but this works in Python 3.6

```
>>> x = list(range(100))
>>> y = list(range(500, 600))
>>> zip_obj = zip(x, y)
>>> my_tuple = tuple(zip_obj)
>>> type(my_tuple)
>>> <class 'tuple'>
>>> tuple_str = str(my_tuple)
>>> tuple_str
'((0, 500), (1, 501), (2, 502), (3, 503), (4, 504), (5, 505), (6, 506), (7, 507), (8, 508), (9, 509), (10, 510), (11, 511), (12, 512), (13, 513), (14, 514), (15, 515), (16, 516), (17, 517), (18, 518), (19, 519), (20, 520), (21, 521), (22, 522), (23, 523), (24, 524), (25, 525), (26, 526), (27, 527), (28, 528), (29, 529), (30, 530), (31, 531), (32, 532), (33, 533), (34, 534), (35, 535), (36, 536), (37, 537), (38, 538), (39, 539), (40, 540), (41, 541), (42, 542), (43, 543), (44, 544), (45, 545), (46, 546), (47, 547), (48, 548), (49, 549), (50, 550), (51, 551), (52, 552), (53, 553), (54, 554), (55, 555), (56, 556), (57, 557), (58, 558), (59, 559), (60, 560), (61, 561), (62, 562), (63, 563), (64, 564), (65, 565), (66, 566), (67, 567), (68, 568), (69, 569), (70, 570), (71, 571), (72, 572), (73, 573), (74, 574), (75, 575), (76, 576), (77, 577), (78, 578), (79, 579), (80, 580), (81, 581), (82, 582), (83, 583), (84, 584), (85, 585), (86, 586), (87, 587), (88, 588), (89, 589), (90, 590), (91, 591), (92, 592), (93, 593), (94, 594), (95, 595), (96, 596), (97, 597), (98, 598), (99, 599))'
>>>
```