# Python - String Stored in a Variable showing as tuple

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I performing concatenation of multiple variables to a string and trying to store it in a list. I want the list to have the string but when i append the list in a loop, the value on the list is shown as tuple. Please help, New to python :)

When i Print :

```
print ( key +' ' +' =', amount1+' ' +' /',amount2+' ' +' /',pincrease)
```

Output is in str :

```
app1  = 53.58  / 54.81  / 2.24% lower.
```

When i append my list :

```
message = ( key +' ' +' =', amount1+' ' +' /',amount2+' ' +' /',pincrease)
message.append(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

output :

```
[('app1  =', '53.58  /', '54.81  /', '2.24% lower.')]
```

I would like to get the value as string in the list.. as

```
["app1  = 53.58  / 54.81  / 2.24% lower."]
```

Comment: I think you should print `message`, instead of `mylist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  this code:

```
( key +' ' +' =', amount1+' ' +' /',amount2+' ' +' /',pincrease)
```

is a tuple.   You might consider using format strings instead of `+` for this kind of thing. Which would make it look more like this:

```
message = f'{key} = {amount1} / {amount2} / {pincrease}'
mylist.append(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

You code is actually working fine, but there is a some small mistake when you append your `message` into the list.

```py
mylist.append(''.join(message))  # this step will remove your tuple
print(mylist)

# ["app1  = 53.58  / 54.81  / 2.24% lower."]
```

- For more information check this question --> [Python 3: Converting A Tuple To A String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436803/6194097)
- If you want to format your string check this question --> [Which is the preferred way to concatenate a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56735266/6194097)